# efficient library to recommend product based on user history

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, recommendation-engine

I have a database of which products every user has viewed and I want to recommend a product based on what similar users have viewed. Is there a Python library that can achieve this? I don't need Netflix quality results, just products that are more likely than not of interest. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out [pysuggest](http://code.google.com/p/pysuggest/).

From the site:

> SUGGEST is a Top-N recommendation
>   engine that implements a variety of
>   recommendation algorithms. Top-N
>   recommender systems, a personalized
>   information filtering technology, are
>   used to identify a set of N items that
>   will be of interest to a certain user.
>   In recent years, top-N recommender
>   systems have been used in a number of
>   different applications such to
>   recommend products a customer will
>   most likely buy; recommend movies, TV
>   programs, or music a user will find
>   enjoyable; identify web-pages that
>   will be of interest; or even suggest
>   alternate ways of searching for
>   information.

Answer (score 4):

**k-Nearest Neighbor** is probably the most commonly implemented algorithm for real-time web-based recommender systems.

In ***NumPy/SciPy*** you have several choices [note: answer updated in dec 12 to reflect updates in *sklearn* library]:

- *nearest neighbors* module in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html#nearest-neighbors) (aka ***sklearn***); this is a sophisticated kNN implementation that includes neighbor weighting and voting as well as a very efficient storage/retrieval component (*ball tree*);
- [scipy.spatial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/spatial.html). I have used this for several projects, though it's unlikely i would use it for my next one given sklearn is now available, which is a more up-to-date implementation of kNN. Still, the spatial module has a **kd-tree class** (*kd-tree* rather than standard numpy array is used by this module to store the data, which along w/ *Voronoi tesselation*, is the most common specialized data structure to    store very large data sets for kNN); in addition, it has methods for several *distance metrics* (aside from Euclidean distance).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another python library to implement a recommender system:

[ocelma / python-recsys](https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys)

It's very simple to use it! See some examples here:
[Quick start¶](http://ocelma.net/software/python-recsys/build/html/quickstart.html)